# PUT with null attribute

Tags: rest, nullable

Occasionally my API receives PUT requests where one of the boolean attributes is set to null. Something like this:

```
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "email": "john.doe@company.com",
  "active": null
}
```

If this would be a PATCH, I would simply ignore the attribute, but in case of PUT, what should I do? My intuition says: set active to false. But I'm not convinced that would be the right REST behavior.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-58):

> 6.5.1.  400 Bad Request

The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
message framing, or deceptive request routing).

I would say you should reject processing of client's request which doesn't pass data validation with a `400 Bad Request` response.

Also note that:

> 4.3.4.  PUT

The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be
**created or replaced** with the state defined by the representation
enclosed in the request message payload.

so, you shouldn't just ignore invalid field values.

However, if you skip data validation and just accept the new resource state as sent by the client, then representation will be is inconsistent with the target resource, and you can try rewriting the request, or failing with `409 Conflict` ([RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-26)):

> An origin server SHOULD verify that the PUT representation is
> consistent with any constraints the server has for the target
> resource that cannot or will not be changed by the PUT.  This is
> particularly important when the origin server uses internal
> configuration information related to the URI in order to set the
> values for representation metadata on GET responses.  When a PUT
> representation is inconsistent with the target resource, the origin
> server SHOULD **either make them consistent**, by transforming the
> representation or changing the resource configuration, **or respond
> with an appropriate error message** containing sufficient information
> to explain why the representation is unsuitable.  The 409 (Conflict)
> or 415 (Unsupported Media Type) status codes are suggested, with the
> latter being specific to constraints on Content-Type values.